# single quotes or not

Tags: quotations

She got mad because I didn't call Bob Principal Bob.

Should it be

She got mad because I didn't call Bob 'Principal Bob.'

thanks

Comment: Why does the Title question contain the word "single"?  Whether single or double quotation marks are used seems totally irrelevant to the description of the question.

Comment: Without quotes it's potentially ambiguous; Principal could be Bob's surname.

Comment: Italics could also be used.

Comment: @RayButterworth In US English, double quotation marks are normally used for actual quotations or speech. The definition of a term *can* use double quotation marks, but more often uses single quotation marks or italics. In short, it *does* make a difference in terms of style, depending on your region.

Comment: @KateBunting Or the person's name could actually be Bob (first name) Principal (middle name) Bob (last name): "Hi, my name is Bob P. Bob. That stands for Bob Principal Bob." But if you add a comma, it would be more explicitly like "Bond, James Bond."

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica, Or it could be "*I didn't call Bob Principal 'Bob'.*", where "Bob Principal" is the speaker's name.